# How to have a variable formula in a foreach loop?

Tags: java, variables, foreach

I have a foreach loop going in my program. I also have two formulas: putPrice and callPrice. Here is my condensed code:

```
public class CallObsArray{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] month = new String[]{"march","april","may"};
        String[] option = new String[]{"call","put"};
        for(String s: month){
            for(String t: option){

                if((callPrice - observedCall[k]) > 0){
                    volatilityB = volatilityC;
                }
                else { 
                    volatilityA = volatilityC;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

When the for loop is going on for the "call" string, I want my program to use the callPrice formula above and when it is "put", the formula I would like is `observedCall[k] - putPrice` in the if statement.

Comment: read this like you have no idea what this is about objectively and really think about how clearly you are communicating your question, *hint: not clear at all* The formatting is horrendous as well, fix that while you are re-writing your question!

Comment: This code doesn't look like it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using Strings to specify functionality is that Strings are not type-safe. You can put whatever data you'd like in a String, and the compiler won't be able to tell you if you're making a mistake.

One way to improve the type safety of your code is to represent each type of function you want to perform. Here's one way to do it.

First, define an interface:

```
public interface Formula {
    public int compute(int observedCall, int price);
}
```

Then create two implementations of that interface; here, they're done as anonymous inner classes:

```
Formula callPriceFormula = new Formula() { 
    @Override
    public int compute(int observedCall, int callPrice) {
        return callPrice - observedCall;
    }
};

Formula putPriceFormula = new Formula() {
    @Override
    public int compute(int observedCall, int putPrice) {
        return observedCall - putPrice;
    }
};
```

Then you can create a `Formula[]` consisting of these two values, and in your for loop, you would call `formula.compute(observedCall, price);`

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you think through your problem.